# IP Camera in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, http-status-code-401

I'm attempting to get a view in Unity3D with an IP camera. Only when I use the URL to access the camera with a script(see below) it gives the 401 Unauthorized error. Now I need to login with a password and username, both admin.

But I'm not sure how to put that in the URL, any help with that? See the code below on what I have so far.

```
//#pragma strict

// http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW.LoadImageIntoTexture.html

var url = "http://192.168.1.30/admin/view.cgi?profile=2&language=en";

function Start () {
    // Create a texture in DXT1 format

    // NOTE: you may want to experiment with different texture formats, specially in a web context
    // https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/TextureFormat.html
    renderer.material.mainTexture = new Texture2D(4, 4, TextureFormat.DXT1, false); 
    Debug.Log(adress);
    Debug.Log(url);
    while(true) {
        // Start a download of the given URL
        var www = new WWW(url);
        // wait until the download is done
        yield www;
        // assign the downloaded image to the main texture of the object
        www.LoadImageIntoTexture(renderer.material.mainTexture);
    }
}
```

==============================================

So now I am using the WWWForm.Headers. Yet when I put it in my code, it gives me a "A field initializer cannot reference the field method or property"

The code is:

public class SEMTEX : MonoBehaviour {

```
// Use this for initialization
//void Start() {
    public WWWForm form = new WWWForm ();
    public string headers = form.headers;
    public byte[] rawData = form.data;
    public string url = "http://192.168.1.101/snapshot.cgi";
    public WWW www = new WWW (url, rawData, headers);
//}

IEnumerator Update (){

    form.AddField ("name", "value");
    headers ["Authorization"] = "Basic " + System.Convert.ToBase64String (System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes ("admin:admin"));
    yield return www;
}
```

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `WWWForm.headers`. [The example in the docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm-headers.html) is doing HTTP basic auth.

Also, if you're planing to update the image often, using an uncompressed texture like `TextureFormat.RGB24` should be much faster.

---

The unity docs was quite outdated, so here's the complete script that continuously updates a webcam and draws it on a screen:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class HttpWebcam : MonoBehaviour {

    public string uri;
    public string username;
    public string password;


    Texture2D cam;


    public void Start() {
        cam=new Texture2D(1, 1, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        StartCoroutine(Fetch());
    }


    public IEnumerator Fetch() {
        while(true) {
            Debug.Log("fetching... "+Time.realtimeSinceStartup);

            WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
            form.AddField("dummy", "field");    // required by WWWForm
            WWW www = new WWW(uri, form.data, new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>() {  // using www.headers is depreciated by some odd reason
                {"Authorization", "Basic " + System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username+":"+password))}
            });
            yield return www;

            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
                throw new UnityException(www.error);

            www.LoadImageIntoTexture(cam);
        }
    }


    public void OnGUI() {
        GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(0,0,Screen.width,Screen.height), cam);
    }

}
```

To run just drag into a GameObject and provide any URI containing a PNG or JPEG. It can also access resources that arent password protected (password is ignored then). For an example you can use: `http://www.sudftw.com/imageppc.php`.

Comment: Edited my post under the '=' line, any idea?

Comment: I added the new code, thanks alot for that by the way! But it gives two more errors, which I think are connected.'

'Assets/Scripts/SEMTEX.cs(28,27): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.WWW.WWW(string, byte[], System.Collections.Hashtable)' has some invalid arguments' 

and


'Assets/Scripts/SEMTEX.cs(28,27): error CS1503: Argument `#3' cannot convert `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>' expression to type `System.Collections.Hashtable''

Comment: I also edited the url, username and password string to say admin, as they should. Like this:
 public string uri = "http://192.168.0.50/snapshot.cgi";
 public string username = "admin";
 public string password = "admin";

Comment: What is your unity3d version? It looks like they changed the API on 4.5. Also: tried to downgrade to 4.3.4f1 and sending headers seems broken there. You should upgrade to 4.5 if possible.

Comment: It works now! Thanks alot! It was indeed the Unity version, I just updated so it's all good.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to Krzysztof's answer, replace the `OnGUI()` method to overlay the camera feed onto an in-game object (eg. like an in-game television screen), instead of drawing it on the whole screen.

```
public GameObject displayPlane;

public void OnGUI()
{
    displayPlane.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = cam;
}
```